# Tensorflow Random segmentation faults

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run the demo code from official tensorflow [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch)
I am attaching the full code (copied and arranged) here for ease

```
import tensorflow as tf

# print("1")
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
import time
import os

# print("2")
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"


# @tf.function
def train_step(x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(x, training=True)
        loss_value = loss_fn(y, logits)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
    train_acc_metric.update_state(y, logits)
    return loss_value


# @tf.function
def test_step(x, y):
    val_logits = model(x, training=False)
    val_acc_metric.update_state(y, val_logits)


inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x1 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputs)
x2 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x1)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, name="predictions")(x2)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# Instantiate an optimizer.
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
# Instantiate a loss function.
loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
train_acc_metric = keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
val_acc_metric = keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
# Prepare the training dataset.
batch_size = 64
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 784))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 784))

# Reserve 10,000 samples for validation.
x_val = x_train[-10000:]
y_val = y_train[-10000:]
x_train = x_train[:-10000]
y_train = y_train[:-10000]

# Prepare the training dataset.
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(batch_size)

# Prepare the validation dataset.
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size)

epochs = 2
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
    start_time = time.time()

    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
        loss_value = train_step(x_batch_train, y_batch_train)

        # Log every 200 batches.
        if step % 200 == 0:
            print(
                "Training loss (for one batch) at step %d: %.4f"
                % (step, float(loss_value))
            )
            print("Seen so far: %d samples" % ((step + 1) * 64))

    # Display metrics at the end of each epoch.
    train_acc = train_acc_metric.result()
    print("Training acc over epoch: %.4f" % (float(train_acc),))

    # Reset training metrics at the end of each epoch
    train_acc_metric.reset_states()

    # Run a validation loop at the end of each epoch.
    for x_batch_val, y_batch_val in val_dataset:
        test_step(x_batch_val, y_batch_val)

    val_acc = val_acc_metric.result()
    val_acc_metric.reset_states()
    print("Validation acc: %.4f" % (float(val_acc),))
    print("Time taken: %.2fs" % (time.time() - start_time))
    print("end")
```

Without any reason, this code enters Segmentation Fault in Tensorflow 2.3.1 right at the beginning

```
>python dummy.py 
2021-03-11 17:45:52.231509: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Interestingly if I put some random print statements at the very start(those `print("1")` etc statements, the code will execute till the end and suffer segmentation fault at the end(redundant output not shown)

```
Start of epoch 1
Training loss (for one batch) at step 0: 1.0215
Seen so far: 64 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 200: 0.9116
Seen so far: 12864 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 400: 0.4894
Seen so far: 25664 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 600: 0.5636
Seen so far: 38464 samples
Training acc over epoch: 0.8416
Validation acc: 0.8296
Time taken: 3.16s
end
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Another observation is, if I uncomment the `@tf.function` on top of my `trainStep` and `testStep` functions, the code enters into segfault again but after it prints
`Start of epoch 0`

Can someone explain what is going wrong with my Tensorflow package?

Comment: I was able to execute above code in my machine without any issues. Seems it is related to installation problem. Can you let us know how did you installed tensorflow and version details of CUDA and cuDNN?

Comment: @TFer2 I figured out the problem. It was due to older version of Ubuntu. I was using 14. After upgrading to 18, the issue got resolved

Comment: That's good to hear.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to older version of Ubuntu. I was using 14. After upgrading to 18, the issue got resolved